# How to output git log with the first line only?

Tags: git, version-control, formatting, logging, commit-message

I am trying to customize the format for `git log`. I want all commits to be shown in one line. Each line should only show the first line of the commit message.
I [found out](http://book.git-scm.com/3_reviewing_history_-_git_log.html) that `git log --pretty=short` should do the trick but on my computer it shows the full log as `git log` does (besides the time stamp).

Further, I tried to use the [placeholders as defined in the man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). Though, I could not find a command to shorten the log message. I tried this line `git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s'` which shows the shorted hash `%h`and the full message `%s` in one line.

I am using `git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0` on Vista.

---

Maybe it has something to do with the way I write my commit messages. Here is an example:

```
Added some functionality.
+ Added print function in Foo class.
+ Added conversion from foo to baz.
```

So, with the example given I only want to be output `Added some functionality.` prepended by the shortend hash.

Comment: `%s` is the subject, not the full message.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you actually want. The `short` format *isn't* all on one line, though (surprise!) `oneline` is. If `oneline` and `%h : %s` aren't what you want, what's wrong with them? In particular, `%s` is the subject, the first line of the commit message. That should indeed be a shortened version. Is it possible you've been making commits with a single long line for the message, and viewing them somehow with word wrapping?

Comment: You totally understand. The problem is that `oneline` and `%s` do not output what we expect, at least on my computer. I updated my post with an example of my commit message. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 815, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
git log --oneline
```

It's an alias for `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`, and displays the "short sha" and "short description", for example:

```
9bee8857 Write more code
831fdd6e Write some code Second line of message
```

The problem is that you are missing an empty line after the first line of your commit message. The command above usually works for me, but I just tested on a commit without empty second line. I got the same result as you: the whole message on one line.

Empty second line is a standard in git commit messages. The behaviour you see was probably implemented on purpose.

The first line of a commit message is meant to be a short description. If you cannot make it in a single line you can use several, but git considers everything before the first empty line to be the "short description". `oneline` prints the whole short description, so all your 3 rows.

Comment: Thanks! You solved the mystery: I do not have an empty line after the first line in my commit message to separate the subject from the rest. Nevertheless, it would be nice if I would be free to put it in or leave it out.

Comment: No problem. In fact, you are free to have the empty line or not. Only that your whole message becomes the short message if you leave it out. I like this short description / detailed description, and I suppose that being limited to one line for the short description was a problem, hence the empty line requirement. You could always pipe the output of `git log` to a filtering script, but I would really advocate writing a short description with empty line.

Comment: There's also `git log --oneline`  --oneline is a built-in shorthand for "--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit" used together.

Comment: how you get rid of the prepended shortened hashtag? Not that it isn't bit-packedly pretty. But without `cut`. That would be `awk`ward... (BTW math Q: what's the odds the next bit in a properly encoded huffman sequence, at the storage level, is on or off? Hint: It's === 50%.)

Comment: that was it tx. Oh, also, I got a page full of s, so I naturally added a `%` for `'%s'`. C-;

Answer (score 222):

Does `git log --oneline` do what you want?

Comment: I don't want the whole commit message to be merged onto one line. I want to see the first line of each commit message only.

Comment: @JJD See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997006/3930247) for that.

Answer (score 143):

If you need to print subject lines ***without commit hashes***:

```
git log --pretty=format:%s
```

This will produce something like this:

```
Upgrade framework to v2
Add a new module
Hotfix for the production crash
```

And as Mathieu mentioned, you can use `%b` for just the body and `%B` for both.

Comment: `%s` for the subject; `%b` for the body; `%B` for both ("raw body" in https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

Answer (score 77):

**Better** and **easier** git log by making an **alias**. Paste the code below to terminal just once for one session. Paste the code to zshrc or bash profile to make it persistant.

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

**Output**

```
git lg
```

**Output** changed lines

```
git lg -p
```

**Alternatively** (recommended)
Paste this code to global .gitconfig file

```
[alias]
  lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

**Further Reading.**
https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log
**Advanced Reading.**
http://durdn.com/blog/2012/11/22/must-have-git-aliases-advanced-examples/

Comment: The example is a nice demo of pretty-format, but "Paste the code below to terminal just once" seems wrong because it does not create an alias for "git lg"

Comment: note to others, if you put this command in batch, replace % with %%, replace ' with "". result=`git log --color --graph --pretty=format:"%%Cred%%h%%Creset -%%C(yellow)%%d%%Creset %%s %%Cgreen(%%cr) %%C(bold blue)<%%an>%%Creset" --abbrev-commit %1` . You can pass -p to this bat file to get changed lines as well

Answer (score 29):

You can define a global alias so you can invoke a short log in a more comfortable way:

`git config --global alias.slog "log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit"`

Then you can call it using `git slog` (it even works with autocompletion if you have it enabled).

Answer (score 13):

If you want to print `commit-id` and `commit message` only

> *`git log  --pretty=format:"%h %s"`*

**`%h`** is shorthand for `hash_id` and **`%s`** shorthand for `subjectName[message_name]`

---

You can show date behind `commit-id` and `message` by this command:

> `git log --pretty=format:"%h   %s %C(yellow)(%cr)"`

`%C` is a shorthand for color, I want to show date with different color for example `(red,green,blue, yellow,...etc)`.

`%cr` is a shorthand for  committer date, relative

---

Or you can use this command for print `hash_id` and the `first word` in the commit message:

> `git log --oneline | awk '{print $1 " "  $2}'`

Or

> `git log --oneline`

Answer (score 12):

Without commit messages, only the hash:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: If you only want the hash... `git log --pretty=format:"%H"`

Comment: If you only want the hash you can also use `git rev-list HEAD`.

Answer (score 7):

if you only want the first line of the messages (the subject):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%s"
```

and if you want all the messages on this branch going back to master:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%s" master..HEAD
```

Last but not least, if you want to add little bullets for quick markdown release notes:

```
git log --pretty=format:"- %s" master..HEAD
```

Comment: Nice touch on adding the bullets before each line!

Answer (score 5):

```
git log --format="%H" -n 1
```

Use the above command to get the commitid, hope this helps.

Comment: I used git log --format="%h %B" -1, and then in javascript, I split on \n and take the first line (which still works even if there is no newline)

Answer (score -10):

if you want to always use `git log` in such way you could add git alias by

`git config --global alias.log log --oneline`

after that `git log` will print what normally would be printed by `git log --oneline`

Comment: This doesn't actually work, because (A. git aliases can't override built-in command names) and (B. There need to be quotes around `"log --oneline"`).