# How to edit multiple commit messages at once during rebase?

Tags: git

I want to reformat the commit message of several commits (30 or so). I had neglected to add a newline after the "short" message in many commits, which is causing issues as described in this question: [How to output git log with the first line only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4479225/252576), so I want to rewrite the commit messages with this newline included.

I ran the command `git rebase -i -p <commit-id of last good commit>`, as explained in this answer: [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180085/252576), then in the editor window that opens, I replaced `pick` with `reword` for the commits whose message I want to edit.

This results in git opening text editor one at a time per commit. I guess it is designed this way because git needs to do a rebase after each change.

However, in this case, I am only changing the commit messages, and not changing any files. Is it possible to speed this up, by opening all the text editor windows at once?

For example, if these windows could be opened in multiple buffers of one text editor process (most text editors support this), then I could use a multi-buffer operation, like the `bufdo` command of gvim.

Comment: Technically it's not a re-*base* after each change, it's a re-*commit*.

Comment: This is the same as what I would like to do: to change a referenced issue/ticket/bug ID in each commit message (~25 consecutive commits) with `git rebase  & sed /old/new/`....

Answer (score 3):

The easy way: just put the right key sequence in your copy-paste buffer and middle-click (or use your terminal emulator's paste functionality) to apply.

The more involved way: use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).  For example, to add an empty line in second position, you'd likely use something like this:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed "1a\\\\"' from..
```

where `from` is a ref to your last good commit.

Comment: Another method: set the "editor" to a command that does the change without human interaction.  E.g., write a script that can runs`sed -i ''` to add a blank line after the first line.  Make sure the script works well, then use `EDITOR=... git rebase ...`.  Rig the script to run the real editor when run on the set of pick-etc commands, and to script the edit when run on each commit-message (which has a predictable file name).